# Mysqldump is created after headers are sent

Tags: php, mysql

The issue at hand is that a blank file is downloaded, but the mysqldump file is created in the back end. How do I make the script wait for the dump to be done, and then  start the download?

```
<?php

$filename = 'sqldump_' . date('YmdHis') . '.sql.gz';
$cmd = 'mysqldump --host=localhost --user=blah --password=blah database | gzip -c > ' . $filename;
passthru($cmd);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/x-gzip-compressed');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

exit(0);
```

Comment: You have to put all the `header()` lines before `passthru()`

Comment: No, mysql is already done. but you need to pass the files content as well _before_ the exit statement.

Comment: Why use passthru if you're dumping to a file?

Comment: Instead of passthru, use `readfile($filename)`

Comment: @MattGibson: It channels diagnostic messages.

Comment: @Barmar I did that also, with the same result

Comment: Did you put it after all the `header()` lines?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I tried that at first and when that didn't work I switched it

Comment: I figured it out. Start with all `header()` lines, except `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));`. Place that line after the passthru and the download knows the file size and correctly downloads it